# Check docker login status through shell script

Tags: json, bash, docker, shell

I am trying to check if a user is already logged in to use `Docker`. From a basic search, I found that when I do `cat ~/.docker/config.json`, the user is not logged in if I get:

```
{
  "experimental" : "disabled",
  "stackOrchestrator" : "swarm",
  "auths" : {

  },
  "credsStore" : "desktop"
}
```

while the user is logged in if I get:

```
{
  "stackOrchestrator" : "swarm",
  "experimental" : "disabled",
  "credsStore" : "desktop",
  "auths" : {
    "https://index.docker.io/v1/" : {

    }
  }
}
```

So I store in a variable: `'docker_login_info=$(command cat ~/.docker/config.json)'` but I'm finding it hard to read this nested map in a shell script and decide that based on the condition that auths has a value inside. I'd appreciate some guidance in this regard.

Comment: I suggest to use `jq` for this job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command will ouput 0 if `auths` is empty or greater than 0 if `auths` has some entries:

```
jq '.auths | length' ~/.docker/config.json
```

If you need the output in a variable you can try this:

```
docker_login_info=`jq '.auths | length' ~/.docker/config.json`
```

You can then use the variable like this in the shell:

```
[ $docker_login_info -eq 0 ] && echo 'User not logged it' || echo 'User logged in'
```

More info about `jq` can be found here: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: I'm curious about the third way of checking and printing the message, what does `$docker_login_info -eq 0` do to determine that the user is not logged in. I essentially do not understand how you extracted information in auths  without explicitly referencing it?

Comment: I did not suggest three ways to check the status but instead just one way.
The output from jq (where I reference explicitly `auths`) is saved in the variable `$docker_login_info`; then this variable can be used anywhere in your code to tell you whether `auths` was empty or not.

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry I missed it. Thanks for the help. :)